# Cannot see drawer when swiped left

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

```
This is the Java file i have for the drawer menu,there are no problems/error logs
```

or anything apparently wrong with the code

```
public class DrawerActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private ListView listView;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.drawer_menu);
setDrawerLayout((DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout));
setListView((ListView)findViewById(R.id.drawerList));
}


public ListView getListView() {
return listView;
}


public void setListView(ListView listView) {
this.listView = listView;
}


public DrawerLayout getDrawerLayout() {
return drawerLayout;
}


public void setDrawerLayout(DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
this.drawerLayout = drawerLayout;
}


}
```

I have made a basic xml layout file for it that looks like this

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 

 android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 >


<FrameLayout 

 android:id="@+id/mainContent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:layout_width="match_parent" 
 android:background="@color/dark_gray"                              
    >       
</FrameLayout>

<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/drawerList"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:entries="@array/activity_logs" 
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:background="@color/dark_gray" 
    android:textColor="@color/gray"

    >        
</ListView>                           
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I really don't see any errors ,I've cleaned the project several times and restarted eclipse
a few times ,also uninstalled and re installed tools in the SDK Manager
out of ideas

Comment: try using this android:layout_gravity="start"

Comment: din't work,also shouldn't the drawer show anyway when you swipe left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not implement it fully. You need to set adapter for items to list in the drawer list. It might be because the drawer list is empty.  This [doc](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) can help you.

Also, I had been using support library for action bar like you did. But it drawer is laggy /not smooth as far as I experienced. And I have migrated to standard actionbar (also increases the min sdk requirement) That is why, you might want to looking at standard actionbar or sherlock action bar. Just saying :)

Good luck.